# The "Datastore.save" method doesn't return a response

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have this code (Node JS) for save an 'entity' in Google Cloud Datastore:

```
'use strict';

// Load libs.
var express  = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var router   = express.Router();
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore'); // Imports the Google Cloud client lib

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId   = 'test-datastore';
const keyFilename = 'test-datastore-48aeec501413.json';

const datastore = new Datastore({
    projectId: projectId,
    keyFilename: keyFilename
});

// URI: '/api/save'
router.post('/save', (req, res, next) => {

    // The kind for the new entity
    const kind = 'Auditoria';

    // key 'undefined'
    const pKey = datastore.key(kind);

    // Prepares the new entity
    //          fechaHora: fechaStrToDate(req.body.fechaHora),
    const auditoria = {
        key: pKey,
        data:
        {
            id:             req.body.id,
            trama:          req.body.trama,
            estado:         req.body.estado
        }
    };

    // Saves the entity
    datastore
        .save(auditoria)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('then');
            return res.status(200).jsonp({
                "test":
                {
                    "code" : 0,
                    "desc" : "success"
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
            return res.status(200).jsonp({
                "test":
                {
                    "code" : 1,
                    "desc" : "error",
                    "errorMessage" : err.message
                }
            });
        });

    console.log('FIN');

}); // END POST

module.exports = router;
```

So when I test the application, I don't know why none of these 'lines' are executed (Does not print in the console):

"console.log('then');"

"console.error('ERROR:', err);"

Just prints this line: "console.log('FIN');"

Any ideas? it would help me a lot.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hey @gecs, would you mind trying this again from a fresh install? I haven't been able to reproduce, so I'm wondering if there was a temporary bug in a transient dependency. Here is a similar issue: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/issues/49

Comment: Which version of the Google Cloud Datastore Node.js Client were you using? Does reverting to a previous version restore functionality?

Comment: Hi @Stephen. Thanks for your suggestion.
It seems that VSCode IDE didn't read environment variable actual value (windows). It needs to restart after some environment variable is modified.
Regards

Comment: Hi @George. Thanks for your suggestion.
I'm using 1.3.3 (version datastore client).
Regards

Comment: Have you tried using a previous version? It may prove relevant.